# How to remove pound from url? [react-router v4]

Tags: react-router-v4

I'm writing client side rendering react application, and using react-router for routing purposes.

I use HashRouter since I handle urls on browser.

I need to remove [hash type](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter/hashType-string) (#) from url. How can I do that? I couldn't find any solution for v4 and hashrouter.

Note: v4 doesn't accept history object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HashRouter then you will get the Hash since that is part of the mechanism that makes it work.

If you move to the BrowserRouter you should still get client side functionality that you are looking for with out the routing.  If serving your code out of a static bucket you might need to update configuration so that you always server the base index.html or whatever your entry point file is.